# Batch Scripting - IF statement not working if SET is called inside another IF

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST "sample.txt" (
    set /p RETRY="Need to re-download file. Proceed (y/n)? "

    echo RETRY is !RETRY!
    if !RETRY!=="y" (
        echo Retrying download now
    ) else (
        echo Retry rejected
    )
) else (
    echo File does not exist
)

pause
```

Basically, I have an IF condition and inside it, I need to get a user input and check its value with another IF statement.

Problem is - variable has been updated and it prints correctly but for some reason, it is being evaluated incorrectly inside the nested IF.  Help?

Actual output:

```
Need to re-download file. Proceed (y/n)? y
RETRY is y
Retry rejected
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Expected:

```
Need to re-download file. Proceed (y/n)? y
RETRY is y
Retrying download now
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: double quotes. `if /i "!RETRY!"=="y"` and why not rather use choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not double quote both sides of the comparison:

```
if /I "!RETRY!"=="y"
```

I would however replace that entire piece of code to use choice instead:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not exist "sample.txt" echo File does not exist & goto :end
choice /c YN /m "Need to re-download file Proceed"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    echo retrying download now
) else (
    echo Retry rejected
)
:end
pause
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!